# Failed to create COM object `WScript.shell': CoInitialize has not been called

Tags: php, com, wsh

At sometime today, this error occurred and the script hanged:

```
[21-Aug-2013 08:35:06] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `WScript.shell': CoInitialize has not been called.
' in C:\path\to\my\script.php:357
Stack trace:
#0 C:\path\to\my\script.php(357): com->com('WScript.shell')
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\path\to\my\script.php on line 357
```

This is the line (**running in a loop**) causing the error:

```
$com = new Com('WScript.shell');
```

This line usually runs fine so I'm not missing any libraries. Why could this happen ?

Answer (score 2):

Go to php.ini and add this line. After that, restart php server. Good luck to you

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

Comment: Thanks but this is already done. The weird thing is that this error occurs at a random time. I mean, the script runs fine for few hours\days, and suddenly, this error starts appearing whenever this line is executed.

Answer (score 1):

That is most likely due to desktop heap allocation error. One way to verify is to go to Windows Event Log (system category) and search for "desktop heap allocation failed" error or warning. As an workaround, you can consider using [shell_exec](http://www.php.net/shell_exec).

For more details about desktop heap allocation error, see [KB 184802](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184802)

Answer (score 0):

Effectively include the library "extension = php_com_dotnet.dll" in php.ini can serve in executing $ command = new Com ('WScript.Shell');
in my case it worked with Apache / 2.2.29 server (Win64) PHP / 3.5.29 mod_ssl / 2.2.29

thanks a lot.